# What purpose does [stackexchange] tag serve?

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

Stumbled upon [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange) today and I cannot think of a reason for its existence. It is often used with:

- [stackoverflow-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-api), [stackexchange-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange-api), and [stackexchage.redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchage.redis).
- Or with [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api), to probably indicate [stackexchange-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange-api).
- Or else with [redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redis), to probably indicate [stackexchange.redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange.redis).

My request:

- Find a question that stands by itself with only [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange), and actually is acceptable (i.e. not like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25986571/1461424)).

Or

- Retag all questions that have both [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange) and [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) with [stackexchange-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange-api).
- <strike>Retag all questions that have both [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) and [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) with [stackoverflow-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-api).</strike> (This appears to be a separate problem, regarding misunderstanding of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow)).
- Retag all questions that have both [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange) and [redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redis) with [stackexchange.redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange.redis).
- Burninate [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange).

Comment: so it isn't possible to have a question about the implementation of Stack Exchange in a programming question that doesn't involve the API?

Comment: @psubsee2003: Like, **I have an assignment to submit tomorrow, how do I implement a question and answer site? Plz gimme teh codez urgentz**?

Comment: @psubsee2003: StackOverflow caters _specific_ problems one encounters in programming. I cannot imagine a question on StackExchange that will fit the site.

Comment: while the wiki may need work to explain the proper usage, my interpreation of the purpose of the tag is for questions about Stack Exchange.  Specifically someone trying to program using the Stack Exchange tools or trying to implement a similar feature in their own site (the API is only 1 example).

Comment: I'd merge [stackoverflow-api] into [stackexchange-api]

Comment: You should call this "We should burninate [stackexchange]" :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list of what I've found so far that [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange) is probably the best tag there:

- [Hide comments from certain users?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35165331/2693146) - This deals with a user of a scriptable extension who wants to hide comments from certain users using the script. It doesn't deal with the API or anything, so [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange) is the best tag for it.
- [How does StackOverflow handle sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30691621/2693146) - This deals with someone curious how SE maps a certain internal key from `localStorage` with a user (if it's even that).
- [Running a Stack Overflow query from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21961189/2693146) - This is a Python programmer asking the best way to search an SE site to improve another answer of theirs, but they're not using the API to do so.
- [How does stackoverflow check for new posts/comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14384446/2693146) - This asks how SE checks for new posts/comments in real time, because the OP wanted to replicate it somewhere else, but they couldn't find any periodic network activity indicative of polling.
- [RSS feeds for other stackexchange pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10162482/2693146) - This asks about RSS feeds in SE, and [rss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rss) + [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange) is arguably the optimal tag configuration here.

I did find one that was completely off: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37491934/2693146. This was someone trying to figure out how SE did a certain HTML/CSS/JS effect, but none of the tags were correct, and were tangentially related at best.

---

I will note that this list covers the majority of questions that this tag is at all necessary for. The rest really don't have any use for them.